# Play framework 2.6.15(sbt 1.1.6)

Tags: java, playframework

I tried Play 2.6.15 with java 9 and 10 but ended up with the following exception.

```
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.setSigningKey(DefaultJwtParser.java:151)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec$JWTFormatter.parse(Cookie.scala:677)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.decode(Cookie.scala:592)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.decode$(Cookie.scala:584)
        at play.api.mvc.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec.decode(Cookie.scala:769)
        at play.api.mvc.FallbackCookieDataCodec.decode(Cookie.scala:755)
        at play.api.mvc.FallbackCookieDataCodec.decode$(Cookie.scala:746)
        at play.api.mvc.DefaultSessionCookieBaker.decode(Session.scala:95)
        at play.api.mvc.CookieBaker.decodeFromCookie(Cookie.scala:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.setSigningKey(DefaultJwtParser.java:151)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec$JWTFormatter.parse(Cookie.scala:677)
```

Does Play 2.6.15 support Java 9 and Java 10?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with 9/10, but the [installation guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Installing) mentions that these versions are not supported.

> Play requires Java 1.8.